# "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;" - while deleting with @Scheduled method invocation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I've faced with the following problem. Error "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;" is appearing while deleting object with @Scheduled method invocation. Error appears only while @Scheduled invocation, I have got an error with the first call of `deleteInactiveOrders()`. If scheduled method invoked manually from the controller - everything is ok, error isn't appeared. I assume that error relates to multithreading issue, but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Service method:

```
@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * *")
public void deleteInactiveOrders() {
   orderDAO.deleteInactiveOrders();
}
```

orderDAO.deleteInactiveOrders():

```
public void deleteInactiveOrders() {
List<Order> allInactiveOrdersList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Order where orderDate <= sysdate-1").list();
     if (allInactiveOrdersList.size() >=1 ){

      for (Order order: allInactiveOrdersList){
          User user = order.getUser();
          user.removeOrder(order);
        }
      }
    }
```

Error:

> DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] [] pool-2-thread-1 delete from orders where
>   orderId=? DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] [] pool-3-thread-1 delete from
>   orders where orderId=? DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] [] pool-3-thread-1
>   delete from orders where orderId=? INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] []
>   pool-2-thread-1 HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC
>   statements ERROR
>   [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler]
>   [] pool-2-thread-1 Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException:
>   Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int orderId;
    .....

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<ExchangeTransaction> exchangeTransactions = new ArrayList<ExchangeTransaction>();

    public int getId() {
        return orderId;
    }
```

UPDATE: i've found solution for this issue. The problem was with the two contexts and the dependencies between them, i mean ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet. Now I work only with one context and this problem has gone.

Comment: Afaik, you are accessing order in your list, so, you cannot delete it at same time.

Comment: But when `deleteInactiveOrders()` is invoked manually from the controller everything is ok. This error happens only with scheduling invocation.

Comment: user.removeOrder(order); in here you simply remove the entity from the list? or you perform a call to DB?

Comment: Here is the code:
`orders.remove(order);` - remove order from the list
`order.setUser(null);` - set null to the User entity variable

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the following statement in your code `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(order);`, you are performing a `user.removeOrder(order);` on an entity thats already attached to session so it will take care of deletion of order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But deleting `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(order);` hasn't affected to error.

Comment: If i am not wrong, your batch is running every 30 second, verify if your process gets over within 30 seconds. Else it might be the case that two threads might be operating on the same object, at least that is what the exception is saying.

Comment: I don't think so. I have got an error with the first call of `deleteInactiveOrders()`.